# Php object list updated through AJAX

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

What i'm trying to do is that i have a list of itens to sale and when someone chooses one of then, i want it to add to a list of objects and show on the same page with a delete button next to it so the user can insert / delete itens and then when it hits the confirm button it would finish the sales.

I have being looking through ajax examples and how to create dynamic components but i'm not sure how i would do that. Any ideas how could i do that?

Here is my javascript function when the table cell gets clicked:

```
function selectRow(id) {
$.ajax
({
    type: "POST",
    url: "venda.php",
    data: {selected: id},
    cache: false,
    success: function(data)
    {
    }
}); 
}
```

The ajax function works but how can i get the php to add the element to html and to add the delete button that references that iten? And at the end i have to get all elements and put it into the client's "bag" aswell.

Comment: php can't edit client html. You have to do that with javascript

Comment: Why don't use some jQuery [shopping-cart plugins](http://www.redfoxmagazine.com/10-jquery-shopping-cart-plugin/)? ([recommended tutorial](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/build-an-ajax-powered-shopping-cart/))

Comment: I can't use any external API. But then how i could do that with javascript and then persist on php?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, there are several ways to do that. One option could be storing the selected items on $_SESSION variable, and then print it as html markup from venta.php Also, you could add events on click to items ( elements) in order to remove them. This is just like a pseudocode, of course, you need to validate the data, at least this try to explain a flow process on how you deal with remove/add items using php, jquery and javascript with no plugins.

shop.php (where the table of items to choose exists):

```
<!-- here you add jquery and your own javascript to play with that -->

<table>
    <tr>
        <td><a name="item_id" href="#">Item one</a></td>
    </tr>
</table>
<div class="my-selected-items"></div>
<a hef="link-to-proceed-order">Proceed order</a>
```

javascript:

```
// add the result of php response to the *selected items* div
function selectRow(id) {
$.ajax
({
    type: "POST",
    url: "venda.php?action=add",
    data: {selected: id},
    cache: false,
    success: function(data)
    {
        $('.my-selected-items').html(data);
        register_delete_action();
    }
}); 
}

function register_delete_action()
{
    $(".remove-item").click(function(){
        $.ajax
        ({
            type: "POST",
            url: "venda.php?action=delete",
            data: {selected: id},
            cache: false,
            success: function(data)
            {
                $('.my-selected-items').html(data);
                register_delete_action();
            }
        }); 
    });
}
```

venta.php

```
$action = $_GET['action'];

switch ($action)
{
    case "add": addItem();
    case: "delete": deleteItem();
}

function addItem(){
    $selected_id = $_POST['selected'];

    if(!array_key_exists('items', $_SESSION))
    {
        $_SESSION['items'] = array();
    }
    $_SESSION['items'][$selected_id] = array("id" => $item['id'], "name" => $item['name']);


    //print the selected items in html markup
    echo  "<ul>";
    foreach ($_SESSION['items'] as $id => $selection)
    {
        echo '<li> <a href="#" class="remove-item" name="' .$selection["name"] . '">' .$selection["name"] . '</a> </li>';
    }
    echo  "</ul>";
}

function deleteItem(){
    $selected_id = $_POST['selected'];
    unset($_SESSION['items'][$selected_id]); 

    //print the selected items in html markup
    echo  "<ul>";
    foreach ($_SESSION['items'] as $id => $selection)
    {
        echo '<li> <a href="#" class="remove-item" name="' .$selection["name"] . '">' .$selection["name"] . '</a> </li>';
    }
    echo  "</ul>";
}
```

Comment: I changed it a bit and it's almost working but i cant get to reload de page or load another to do the actions. Here's the code after the 'Confirm' button has been pressed: function confirmar() {var jSon = []; var divMenu = document.getElementsByTagName("fieldset");
for (var i = 0; i < divMenu.length; i++) {
  jSon.push({id: divMenu[i].id}); 
 } 
$.ajax
     ({
         type: "POST",
         url: "confirma.php",
         data: {itens: "X"},
         cache: false,
         success: function(data)
         {
    
         }
    });
}

but it doesnt work.

Comment: there you go with the confirm code. on the confirma.php im just printing the $_POST values to see if i get something.

Comment: I see to mistakes: 1. json var should be declared as `var jSon = {};` 2. If you want to pass the json var, you need to throw `$.ajax ({ type: "POST", url: "confirma.php", data: jSon, cache: false` ... so trid that.

Comment: im sending a list of json, even if i change it. It doesnt do anything. It doesnt load the confirma.php with the values. Should i call somenthing on the success function?

Comment: yes, if your confirma.php makes echo of some values, it will be route to `data` parameter of `success function`. You need to set that data to some html element, like div

Comment: It doesnt echo, it should persist the bought items. What should i call on success?

Comment: the success function should print (at least in your case) a message in your document, try putting for example, `document.write('ajax executed');`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13917/discussion-between-gilson-and-manix)

Answer (score 0):

JS:

```
function selectRow(id) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "venda.php",
        data: {selected: id},
        cache: false,
        success: function(data)
        {
            $('css_selector of div you want the stuff displayed in').append(data);
        }
    }); 
}
```

PHP:

```
$input = $_POST['selected'];

// do stuff with input

echo $output; // echo data to be returned
```